# Dual boot W10/xubuntu: fast startup removed but since I put to sleep W10 once I couldn't mount that partition where windows os is installed

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, mount, xubuntu, suspend

yet again the umpteenth Q. about failed mounts and dual boots.

I've previously **resolved** an issue where the infamous **fast start-up** prevent xubuntu to mount every drives except of course  itself. Recently I once put 10 to sleep/suspension/lock (I'm not sure how it's called in English, anyway **it isn't hibernation** because the **option isn't active**) and since then **I could't mount that drive where windows is installed**.

Thanks alot in advance for the replies, patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even when you say : it isn't hibernation because the option isn't active ...

Boot Windows - open **command prompt as administrator** and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

Shutdown your computer completely (do NOT reboot) - Turn on the PC.

Boot Xubuntu, now you should be able to mount the Windows partition.

Comment: Ok, I'll try, surely you're right. I think you found something wrong in that statement: "it isn't hibernation because the option isn't active". Afaik you have to create space for hibernation and you can turn off that options. I believed that file couldn't exist. The guy who help me set up the dual boot loathes hibernation and never set it up. Thanks again.

Comment: You were obviously right. There are a lot of similar question with the same solution, and I bothered the community anyway eheh. I was sure that hibernation "didn't exist" if not in a fast starup status . So why sleep don't go away after you shut down the pc? There was, actually, an hyberfil.sys in W10 drive.

Comment: @ScientistorPhilosopher "hibernate" can still exist, so you need to actually force the system to go into shutdown.  Reboot isn't enough.  (That's why the command given by cl-netbox worked)